# Create a user while sending task to Celery give me an error: User matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-celery

I have setup a rest API with DRF (Django Rest Framework). One of the API functions consists of creating a user account (a.k.a. register).

Once the user is "created", I send a task to celery to send a confirmation email.

But when the task is executed by the celery worker, an error occurred:

> DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

The task takes a user id and nothing more. Then I try to make a call to the DB. And it is at this moment that it fails.

At this exact moment, I am pretty sure the user isn't created in the database because the create() method has finished.

If I had a sleep() in my task, it works.

So my question is:

How can I make sure my user is created into the DB before sending the task to Celery ?

I am using Django 1.9.x

**UPDATE 1**

tasks.py

```
@shared_task(name='users.utils.send_activation_email')
def send_activation_email(url, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        # ...
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # handle exception
```

serializers.py

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create(username=user_data['email'], email=user_data['email'], is_active=False)
    user.set_password(user_data['password'])
    user.save()

    user_profile = user.profile
    user_profile.language = get_language() or settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
    user_profile.display_name = validated_data['display_name']
    user_profile.save()
    user_profile.generate_activation_key()

    request = self.context['request']
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('user_confirm', kwargs={'activation_key': user.profile.activation_key}))
    send_activation_email.delay(url, user.id)  # Celery task
    subscribe_to_newsletter.delay(user.id, True)  # Celery task

    return user_profile
```

**UPDATE 2**

After reviewing my settings, I found this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '*****',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

I disabled *ATOMIC_REQUESTS* and it worked!

Comment: Not enough to go by but I think you have uncommited data by the time the celery task is executed. If you are not running in auto commit mode make sure that the transaction is commited before passing on the task to celery.

Comment: You can put the registration part in the task to make sure the user is created and email is sent in the background. Please notice that in this case you need to validate the data(username being unique or whatever) before sending task to celery.

Comment: @e4c5 that's exactly what happened when you said I have uncommited data. After reviewing my code, I noticed I put ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True in my database config. After removing it, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django signal, [django.db.models.signals.post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/) which send signal to the receiver after a model’s save() method is called

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signal import post_save

def create_user_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        #send email to the user

post_save.connect(create_user_callback, sender=User)
```